# renaming a client workspace root folder in perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

warm greetings.

My  repo size is almost 20 GB.i download all the code to my local workspace which is initially under C:\P4 (capital P). now for the project requirement, i manually changed the folder to 'p4 (lower case p)' and then using p4v i tried to rename the workspace root folder from P4 to p4. but it didnt work out.

I loggeed out and logged in but still in p4v it is showing capital P4 as root folder instead of small p.

But unfortunately, i can see lot of files as changelist under my pending items.

could you people help me in renaming the workspace root folder and revert these changed files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive (but case-aware).  Why do you need to change your root from C:\P4 to c:\p4?  It won't matter at all to Perforce.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows OS, the lower-case and upper-case should not matter as Mark already stated. Here are the documented steps on 'Changing the location of your workspace':

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-23905